# Excecute only if data is not filtered

Tags: excel, vba

My vba code shall only run on lines that are visible after filtering.

My code shall return a msgbox (and do other things) for each line in my table1.
If the line is "filtered away" and thus not shown, the code shall go to next line, without showing the msgbox etc.

Table1 look like this:

Name      FatherName    Zip

Peter     Carl          3200

Jacob     Eric          2800

Christian Carl          3400

I have tried to skip lines with higth = 0 or EntireRow.Hidden
But without succes.

I am sure I am doing a simple thing in a wrong way. But please advice

```
Dim i As Integer
    Range("Tabel1[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
For i = 1 To 3
MsgBox ("hey")
Next i
```

The codes shows a message box for all line, regardsless if they are filtered away or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SpecialCells()` on `DataBodyRange` of wanted column of your Table

```
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    MsgBox ("hey from row " & rng.Row)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. It works on the simple vba I showed. In my real vba I have a loop etc. I will try use your suggestion in the real vba as well.

Comment: Thank yuo once again. Yes, I accept your answer. It surely helped me forward.

Comment: To accept the answer click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in